# why can a service create a webview?

Tags: android, webview, intentservice

Ok so I was trying out some stuff in a service and I saw that you could create a new webview in a service and load a url to it all in the background without the user ever knowing using :

```
WebView wv = new WebView(context);
wv.loadUrl("http://example.com")
```

so basically you can have an app generating website views for any website in the back without the user ever knowing. Why is it permitted to  create a WebView in a service if the user isnt ever going to interact with it ? And why does Android allow it ?

Comment: Object creation doesn't know what a service vs. application vs. AmroWidget is.

Comment: One thing about this, it allows the webview to be used as a script engine. Really not optimal though